# How can i migrate tables from certain oracle USER/SCHEMA using Kettle/Pentaho?

Tags: mysql, oracle, pentaho, database-migration, kettle

I want to migrate the tables/data from one Oracle Schema (SISPEX) using the Copy Tables Wizard feature.

Actually, the oracle JNDI connection in my kettle file is like:

```
orclLocal/type=javax.sql.DataSource    
orclLocal/driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver    
orclLocal/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/pdborcl.df.cgu    
orclLocal/user=system
orclLocal/password=password
```

But when i create this oracle connection at kettle and click to "explore", it shows the desired tables under the Schema "SISPEX". And the "Tables" option is empty.
How can i get the tables of the SISPEX to appear at the "Tables" list?
I need that to use the Copy Tables Wizard and migrate those tables/data to my MySql Database.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using JNDI and not Oracle's Native JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't with the copy tables wizard. It's a known bug:

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-4442

Just write a simple ETL instead - Table Input -> table output.